# Can someone help me understand the solution to these two simple combinatoric problems?

Tags: combinatorics

I was hoping someone can shine light on these two simple combinatoric problems.

Suppose I have a class of 10 students. How many ways can I divide the class into 2 groups of 5? How many ways can I divide the class into a group of 3 and a group of 7?

The answer to the first and second questions are $\frac{1}{2!}\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{5}=126$ and $\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{7}=840$ respectively. My question is how come I am dividing by $2!$ in the first question? Why not the second? Could anyone prove why?

Comment: Phrasing is, unfortunately, important.  In the first problem, if you asked "how many ways are there to create two teams, $A$ and $B$, each with $5$ students" the answer would not have the $\frac 12$ term, because now you have distinguished the two groups.  As stated, however, the groups are not distinct so swapping them does not change the arrangement.

Comment: For the first problem, change the problem to a class of 4 students, with 2 groups, with 2 in each group.  Manually count the # of distinct ways of dividing this class of 4 people, and then compare that with $\binom{4}{2}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the two groups are not distinguishable, as they are both groups of $5$. So choosing e.g. ABCDE as one group and FGHIJ as the second group is really the same as choosing FGHIJ as the first group and ABCDE as the second group. In contrast, with the second case, as it's groups of $3$ and $7$, the groups are naturally distinguishable, since they are of different sizes and so you can't reverse the order of choosing them. If you choose e.g. ABC first and then DEFGHIJ second, then there is no reverse of choosing DEFGHIJ first, since you can only choose $3$ in your first group (hence why you are doing $\binom{10}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Given 10 people, you can pick 5 students to go into the second group, the remaining 5 automatically being the first group.  You have 10 choices for the first student, leaving 9 students.  Then you have 9 choices for the second student, leaving 8 students, then 8 choices, then 7, then 6.  So there are $10(9)(8)(7)(6)= \frac{10!}{5!}= 30240$ choices.  However, that treats the same 5 students, chosen in a different order as being a different group.  Since there are 5! different orders for 5 students, we need to divide by 5! getting $\frac{10!}{5!5!}= \begin{pmatrix}10 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}= \frac{30240}{120}= 252$.  If the two groups are "indistinguishable" as lulu suggests, we need to divide by an additional 2 gettint 126.

For group of 3 and 7 we can do similarly.  There are 10 ways to choose the first student to go into the new group, then 9, then 8.  That is 10(9)(8)= 720 in a specific order so 720/3!= 720/6= 120 ways because order is not important.  A set of 3 **is** distinguishable from a set of 7 so we do not need to divide by 2.

(If you want to do this "the hard way" you can
calculate the number of ways to pick 7 from a set of 10:  (10)(9)(8)(7)(6)(5)(4)/7!= (10)(9)(8)(7)(6)(5)(4)/[(7)(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)]= (10)(9)(8)/[(3)(2)(1)]= (10)(3)(4)= 120.)